# jquery dropdown modify selected text but display the original value of the previously selected text on a subsequent click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I my ASP.NET MVC4 app in Visual Studio 2012, I have a dropdownlist as follows:

```
<select name="ddlID" id="ddlID">
  <option value="1">None</option>
  <option value="2">White ($4.72)</option>
  <option value="3">Black ($5.90)</option>
  <option value="4">Blue ($5.90)</option>
</select>
```

After user selects an item from the list, I need to change the display of the selected text to  "White" if "White ($4.72)" is selected, to "Black" if "Black ($5.90)" is selected etc.

I wrote the change even as follows:

```
$('#ddlID').change(function () {
   var selText = $('#ddlID option:selected').text();
   var i = selText.indexOf(" ");
   $('#ddlID option:selected').text(selText.substring(0, i));
 });
```

The above code works except that if a user changes his/her mind and clicks again to choose a different item or see the list again, the previously selected item still displays as modified text. For instance, if user selected "White ($4.72)" the display would change correctly to "White" but if the user changes his/her mind and clicks again on the dropdwon to decide which ones he/she wants to select, the user sees the following list:

```
None
White
Black ($5.90)
Blue ($5.90)
```

Once the user clicks again, I need to display the original list as:

```
None
White ($4.72)
Black ($5.90)
Blue ($5.90)
```

Please help.

Thanks..Nam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `data` method to assign or read some information about an element. For example:

```
 $('#elem').data('some-info', 15);
 console.log($('#elem').data('some-info')); // 15
```

In your case, you could iterate over each option on the page load and set its original text in a data property. Then, on the dropdown change event, you could reload this data to every option to restore the original text before changing to the new one.

```
// sets the original text in a data property for each option
$('#ddlID option').each(function() {
    $(this).data('original-text', $(this).text()); 
});

$('#ddlID').change(function () {
    // put back the original text to each option
    $(this).find('option').each(function() {
        $(this).text($(this).data('original-text')); 
    });

    var selText = $('#ddlID option:selected').text();
    var i = selText.indexOf(" ");
    $('#ddlID option:selected').text(selText.substring(0, i));
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/cSnnh/

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
<select name="ddlID" id="ddlID">
    <option value="1" data-text="None" data-value="">None</option>
    <option value="2" data-text="White" data-value="White ($4.72)">White ($4.72)</option>
    <option value="3" data-text="Black" data-value="Black ($5.90)">Black ($5.90)</option>
    <option value="4" data-text="Blue" data-value="Blue ($5.90)">Blue ($5.90)</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#ddlID').change(function () {
                $(this).find('option').each(function () {
                    var obj = $(this);
                    if (obj.is(':selected'))
                    {
                        obj.text(obj.attr('data-text'))
                    } else {
                        obj.text(obj.attr('data-value'))
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```